# How to ignore ThenInclude's related data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core 2.0.

I have the following code:

```
return _context.Pessoas
    .Include(x => x.ListasXPessoas).ThenInclude(l => l.Lista)
    .Take(100);
```

Pessoas and Listas have a many-to-many relationship, ListasXPessoas is the join table.

I don't want to return the related data of the Listas entity, as it cycles back to Pessoas. It is defeating the purpose of the `Take(100)`. Is there a way to turn off this behavior, or is executing a SQL command the only way?

Comment: You can ignore ThenIncludes by not adding it to LINQ. Why not `Include(x => x.ListasXPessoas).Take(100);`

Comment: I want to load the Listas data (in the ThenIncludes)... The thing is, I want to stop there. EF is loading the Listas related data, i.e., loading ListasXPessoas again all the way back to Pessoas. So my resulting JSON is like Pessoas/ListasXPessoas/Listas/ListasXPessoas/Pessoas.

Comment: Hmm, that's normal I guess. It's just referencing back to its Parent. Debug your query and make sure it doesn't do anything weird. Are you worried about what EF puts in memory? Also, remember that it doesn't actually run the query until you do the `Take()` so you can also do `Select()` statements before you `Take()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview

Comment: The code is working. I just want to change its behavior. The problem is that I have 150,000 Pessoas elements... I take only the top 100, but when the ThenIncludes references back its its Parent, as you said, I end up with a 50,000+ lines JSON.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to remove those `Include().ThenInclude()` and use a `Select` with an anonymous type / DTO

Comment: You should map the Entity to some type of object that you would serialize to JSON. Don't serialize the EF Entity, create an object that you would use to transfer the data over and map it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with the includes, I don't think recursive references effect performance unless you loop over them.  The issue is that when you serialize to json you are ending up in endless loop.

Tell json formatters to ignore recursive references:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters(opt => opt.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Comment: Already done... Although it's a good tip and solves a problem I had in the past, it doesn't solve my current problem.

Comment: so post an answer, don't forget SO created not only to answer your questions